# C# JSON anonymous serialization

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

**I am trying to serialize some JSON for an API call:**

```
string f5Name = "MyBigIpName";
string poolName = "myPoolName";
string postJson2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
    new
    {
        f5 = new {
            f5Name = new {
                poolName = memberState
            },
        }
    }
);
```

**This results in the following JSON:**

```
{
    "f5": {
        "f5Name": {
            "poolName": {
                "member": {
                    "address": "10.0.0.0",
                    "port": 80
                },
                "session_state": "STATE_DISABLED"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**However, what I am really looking to do is produce this JSON:**

```
{
    "f5": {
        "MyBigIpName": {
            "myPoolName": {
                "member": {
                    "address": "10.0.0.0",
                    "port": 80
                },
                "session_state": "STATE_DISABLED"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to have the f5Name and poolName property names be dynamic so that I can produce the above JSON?  I am using Newtonsoft.JSON (JSON.NET)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you could do something with a `dynamic` type or not, but you for sure can do something with Dictionaries:

```
var obj = new
{
    f5 = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        {
            f5Name, new Dictionary<string, object> {
                {poolName, memberState}
            }
        }
    }
}
string postJson2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

For what you are intending, you'd need to resolve your names in a contract resolver. Something like:

```
private class MyContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
  private Dictionary<string,string> _translate;
  public MyContractResolver(Dictionary<string, string> translate)
  {
    _translate = translate;
  }
  protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
  {
    var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
    string newPropertyName;
    if(_translate.TryGetValue(property.PropertyName, out newPropertyName))
      property.PropertyName = newPropertyName;
    return property;
  }
}
```

And then:

```
string f5Name = "MyBigIpName";
string poolName = "MyPoolName";     
var _translator = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
  { "f5Name", f5Name },
  { "poolName", poolName },
};
string postJson2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
    new
    {
      f5 = new {
        f5Name = new {
            poolName = memberState
        },
    },
    new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new MyContractResolver(_translator) });
```

If you use C# 6, you could benefit from `nameof` and/or make it cleaner with a dictionary intializer:

```
var _translator = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
  [nameof(f5Name)] = f5Name ,
  [nameof(poolName)] = poolName ,
};
```

The dictionary creation process could be automated easily too :-)